# Select Into the value with Bulk collect

Tags: plsql, bulk

First I created a type and a table type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LAB_LOADING_OBJECT_T
AS
  object
  (
    STUDYID  VARCHAR2(300),
    USUBJID  VARCHAR2(300),
..... /*So many columns, so I hide them*/
);
  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LAB_LOADING_TABLE_T
AS
  TABLE OF LAB_LOADING_OBJECT_T;
```

Then I create an table, the column is same with the LAB_LOADING_OBJECT_T mentioned above:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_EFC11319_LAB_LOADING_T
  (
    STUDYID  VARCHAR2(300),
    USUBJID  VARCHAR2(300),
..... /*So many columns, so I hide them*/
);
```

At last,I tried to select the value into the table called TMP_EFC113_LAB_LOADING_T:

```
SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO TMP_EFC11319_LAB_LOADING_T 
FROM EFC113$STABLE.LBLL ;
```

The LBLL's columns are same with the table TMP_EFC113_LAB_LOADING_T. But I encountered a error message:

```
-------------
ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
*Action:   None.
Error at Line: 2 Column: 1
--------------
```

I don't know what brings the error.

Comment: Try to use `SELECT LAB_LOADING_OBJECT_T(STUDYID,...)` instead and reduce the members for testing.

Comment: Is EFC113$STABLE a table or a schema (user)?  Is LBLL a table or a column?  If it's a column what is its datatype?

Comment: @BobJarvis EFC113$STABLE.LBLL is a view, whose structure is same with the type I created.

Comment: @Toru I tried your method, but still failed. I'm not sure where is the error. So right now, I think I have to use CREATE TABLE XXX AS (SELECT * FROM ...)

Comment: Which database version? I would start with a _very_ simple example to see if it works at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the type doesn't get involved here at all.  It looks like you're trying to SELECT from a view (EFC113$STABLE.LBLL) and insert into a table (TMP_EFC11319_LAB_LOADING_T).  If that's the case, the way to do this is not to try to do a BULK COLLECT into the table - you need to use an INSERT...SELECT... in a manner similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO TMP_EFC11319_LAB_LOADING_T (STUDYID, USUBJID, ...)
  SELECT STUDYID, USUBJID, ...
    FROM EFC113$STABLE.LBLL
```

Or, as you discovered, you can do

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_EFC11319_LAB_LOADING_T
  SELECT *
    FROM EFC113$STABLE.LBLL
```

Share and enjoy.